# Nested map in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi everyone i am new in react native and i am try to create dropdown list with detail. Below is my code first array values is showing but experiences array value not showing kindly assist me about this issue.

```
    import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
const data = [
  {
    name: "Jude",
    position: "Developer",
    experiences: [
      {
        id: 0,
        job: "React UI Developer",
        period: "2017-2018",
        description:
          "I love Creating beautiful Smart UI with React js and styled components",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        job: "React/ Redux UI Developer",
        period: "2017-2018",
        description:
          "I love Creating beautiful Smart UI with React js and styled components",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Mikes",
    position: "Developer",
    experiences: [
      {
        id: 0,
        job: "React UI Developer",
        period: "2017-2018",
        description:
          "I love Creating beautiful Smart UI with React js and styled components",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        job: "React/ Redux UI Developer",
        period: "2017-2018",
        description:
          "I love Creating beautiful Smart UI with React js and styled components",
      },
    ],
  },
];

function ExpandList(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data.map(({ name, position, experiences }) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
            {experiences.map((checkaa) => {
              <Text key={checkaa.id}>{checkaa.job}</Text>;
            })}
          </View>
        );
        
      })}
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  mainList: {},
  subCategoryTwo: {
    fontSize: 90,
  },
});

export default ExpandList;
```

when i am try to get experiences array values its showing nothing, i am stuck in this problem from one days.

Answer (score 1):

Your second map lacks for return keyword so i modified it as following:

```
function ExpandList(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data.map(({ name, position, experiences }) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
            {experiences.map((checkaa) =>{
               return <Text key={checkaa.id}>{checkaa.job}</Text>
            })}
          </View>
        );
        
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```